# Why is the test accepted when an Exception is not being handeled properly

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

Consider this class

```
package at.jku.ssw.queens;

public class Queens {

public static Queens create(int n) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if (n < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    return new Queens(n);
}
// TODO: fields
private int board[][];
private int nOfQueens;

public Queens(int n) {
    // TODO
    this.board = new int [n][n];
    this.nOfQueens = nOfQueens;
}

public int getSize() {
    // TODO
    return board.length;
}

public int getNQueens() {
    // TODO
    return nOfQueens;
}
//Hilfsmethoden
public boolean checkCol(char col) {
    return col == 'A' || col == 'B' || col == 'C' || col == 'D' || col == 'E' || col == 'F' || col == 'G' || col == 'H';
}
//Hilfsmethoden
public boolean checkRow(int row) {
    return row >= 1 && row <= board.length;
}

public State setQueen(int row, char col) throws QueensException {
    // TODO
    if (!checkRow(row) || !checkCol(col)) {
        throw new InvalidPositionException();
    } else if (hasQueen(row, col)) {
        throw new InvalidMoveException();
    } else if (checkRow(row) && checkCol(col)) {
        board[row+1][col-65] = 'Q';
        nOfQueens++;
    }
    return getGameState();
}

public State removeQueen(int row, char col) throws QueensException {
    // TODO
    if (!checkRow(row) || !checkCol(col)) {
        throw new InvalidPositionException();
    } else if (!hasQueen(row, col)) {
        throw new InvalidMoveException();
    } else if (hasQueen(row, col)) {
        board[row+1][col-65] = 0;
        nOfQueens--;
    }
    return getGameState();
}


public boolean hasQueen(int row, char col) throws InvalidPositionException {
    // TODO
    if (!checkRow(row) || !checkCol(col)) {
        throw new InvalidPositionException();
    } else
        return board[row+1][col-65] == 'Q';
}

public State getGameState() {
    int numberOfQueens = getNQueens();

    if (numberOfQueens == getSize()) {
        return State.COMPLETE;
    } else if (numberOfQueens < getSize()) {
        return State.INCOMPLETE;
    }
    return State.INVALID;
}

public void clear() {
    // TODO
    removeAll();
    nOfQueens = 0;
}
public void removeAll() {
    for(int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
        for(int col = 0; col < board.length; col++) {
            board[row][col] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

}

And this JUnit Test class:

```
package at.jku.ssw.queens.test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import at.jku.ssw.queens.Queens;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class QueensTest {

    @Test
    void testCreate() { //passt
        assertNotNull(Queens.create(5));
        assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> Queens.create(-1));
    }

    @Test
    void testGetSize() { // passt
        Queens queen = Queens.create(5);
        assertEquals(queen.getSize(), 5);
    }

    @Test
    void testgetNQueens() { // index 5 out of bound for lenght 5
        Queens queen = Queens.create(5);
        try {
            queen.setQueen(2, 'B');
            assertTrue(queen.hasQueen(2, 'B'));
            queen.setQueen(3, 'C');
            assertTrue(queen.hasQueen(3, 'C'));
            queen.setQueen(1, 'E');
            assertTrue(queen.hasQueen(1, 'E'));
            queen.setQueen(4, 'F');
            assertTrue(queen.hasQueen(4, 'F'));
            queen.setQueen(5, 'H');
            assertTrue(queen.hasQueen(5, 'H'));

        } catch (QueensException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        assertEquals(5, queen.getNQueens());

    }

    @Test
    void testSetQueen() { // Invalid exception
        Queens queen = Queens.create(5);
        assertThrows(InvalidPositionException.class, () -> queen.setQueen(-1, 'H'));
        try {
            queen.setQueen(1, 'A');
            assertTrue(queen.hasQueen(1, 'A'));
            queen.setQueen(8, 'H');
            assertTrue(queen.hasQueen(8, 'H'));
        } catch (QueensException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Test
    void testRemoveQueen() { //passt
         final Queens queen = Queens.create(5);
        try {
            queen.setQueen(1,'A');
        } catch (QueensException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            queen.removeQueen(1,'A');
        } catch (QueensException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            fail();
        }
    }
    @Test
    void testhasQueen() { //passt
        Queens queen = Queens.create(5);
        try {
            assertFalse(queen.hasQueen(2, 'B'));
            try {
                queen.setQueen(3,'A');
            } catch (QueensException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            assertTrue((queen.hasQueen(3, 'A')));
        }
        catch (QueensException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            fail();
        }
        assertThrows(InvalidPositionException.class,() -> queen.hasQueen(2,'Y'));
    }

    @Test
    void testGameState() { // index out of bound
        Queens queen = Queens.create(5);
        try {
            queen.setQueen(1,'A');
        } catch (QueensException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            queen.setQueen(3,'C');
        } catch (QueensException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            queen.setQueen(2,'F');
        } catch (QueensException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        assertEquals(State.INCOMPLETE,queen.getGameState());
        try {
            queen.setQueen(2, 'F');
        } catch (QueensException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        assertEquals(State.INVALID,queen.getGameState());
    }

    @Test
    void testClear() { //invalid exception
        Queens queen = Queens.create(5);
        try {
            queen.setQueen(1,'B');
        } catch (QueensException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            queen.removeQueen(3,'A');
        } catch (QueensException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        queen.clear();
        assertEquals(0,queen.getNQueens());
    }
}
```

Now I am facing a problem that confuses me. The methods testSetQueen and testClear, are accepted by IntelliJ as successful, meaning the test passes. But on the console, I get this error for the testClear method

> at.jku.ssw.queens.test.InvalidMoveException
> at at.jku.ssw.queens.Queens.removeQueen(Queens.java:61)

And this for the testSetQueen method

> at.jku.ssw.queens.test.InvalidPositionException
> at at.jku.ssw.queens.Queens.setQueen(Queens.java:46)

The method getNQueens and getGameState are producing an ArrayIndexOutOfBound exception, and the other methods work fine. My question is how come that some methods work fine but others don't when the method I get an error in(setQueen) is used in every other test method. What is producing the Exception error there, since in the other methods it works fine? The exception is supposed to be thrown when a position is invalid, hence when checkRow and checkCol are false, could it be that the problem lies in the way I implement these 2 methods?

Comment: It's hard to see what you're trying to test exactly. But I would not be surprised if the try-catch blocks with simple `printStackTrace()` calls is part of the problem. Why do you have those try-catch blocks? If an exception is thrown, and you're not asserting that is _should_ be thrown via `assertThrows`, then shouldn't the test _fail_? In other words, why not let the exception propagate and fail the test?

Comment: Hmmm okay,well I had the try catch blocks by setQueen because it wouldnt let me compile it since the exception was not handeled.I have not tried it with assertThrows although that would make a lot sense,I'll give it a shot

Comment: `else if (!hasQueen(row, col)) throw new InvalidMoveException();` in the removeQueen method seems self-explanatory.  You are trying to remove a queen that you never set.

Comment: Well that was not the intent,I wanted to check if the queen is there if not you cannot remove it hence throw the exception (invalid move) What other way would I be able to throw this exception if not to check if hasQueen is false?

Comment: You can define your test methods to throw checked exceptions. Don't use `assertThrows` unless the exception is _meant to be thrown_. If the exception is not meant to be thrown then the test should be allowed to fail. And if the test fails you need to figure out why and fix the problem (whether the problem is in the being-tested code or the test code itself).

Comment: Do the tests give the same results i.e when you run it with Maven?

Comment: IntelliJ at one time reused the test instance for speed. State changing tests might therefore behave differently.